# Views with manually position of content type item and load more

Tags: views, nodes

I have to content types "article" and "jobs" and i'd like to create a view where i can say on position 1 is the newest article, on position 2 is the second newest on position 3 is the newest job and on position 4 is the second newest and so on.

i think manually sorting or positioning is not an option, cause i want to use the load more function.

is there a way to handle this?

best regards

UPDATE:

to prevent missunderstandings: it should look like this:

- -- 1. article --
- -- 2. article --
- -- 1. job --
- -- 2. job --
- -- 3. article --
- -- 3. job --
- -- 4. job --
- Load more
- -- 4. article --
- -- 5. job --
- -- 5. article --
- -- 6. article --
- -- 6. job --

so i think

> sort criterias

are not an option

Comment: there is something called `sort criteria` in the views settings on the left site. try adding one

Comment: ah sorry. missing facts.
-> after the 4th node it should show the third newest article and then the third newest Job.
i'll update the question.